# Why does the Internet drop when downloading custom maps?

Tags: starcraft-2

This is something I've fixed recently and thought I'd document for benefit of others, as it's so obscure.

When anyone on my network downloads a custom StarCraft 2 map, the map download will fail (or appear to fail and later work) and all connections (even on other computers) will be dropped; they'll sign out of battlenet, skype, msn, and pings will time out for a brief moment.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to fire up cmd and reduce [MTU size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit);

```
 netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "Local Area Connection" mtu=1432 store=persistent
```

Where "Local Area Connection" is the device name for the adapter you connect to bnet through.

---

The problem was the router; Belkin F5D7633-4. Even the latest firmware only allows TCP/IP packets to be ~1492 bytes, despite 1500 being ethernet max. My theory is that the router was fragmenting the packets, and then either this process or the response from battlenet to these router-fragmented packets caused the router to crash.

The MTU value I determined following [this process](http://www.dslreports.com/tweaks/MTU);

- Open an administrative MSDOS command prompt
- ping -l 1472 -f google.com
- Reduce 1472 until you no longer get the "packet needs to be fragmented" error message
- Add 28 more to this (since you specified ping packet data size, not including a packet header of 28 bytes)
- This value is your max MTU

Comment: Yikes, a router that can't handle the default Ethernet MTU size!?  Maybe it's time to get a new router...